# Do I need to initialize a java object reference to null like I do in c++

Tags: java, reference, initialization

In c++, it's mandatory to initialize an empty pointer to the NULL value, otherwise, it will refer to an invalid memory block.
In java, is it mandatory to initialize an empty object reference to null?

Comment: [If you don't have an IDE handy.](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: There is no chance to dereference an invalid pointer in Java. Depending on kind, they are either pre-initialized to `null` or you are not allowed to dereference them.

Comment: It's not mandatory in C++, it's just a good idea.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I agree. It's not mandatory, but it should! A lot of c++ bugs are created because of uninitialized pointer.

Comment: I'm going to disagree with all of you. It's never a good idea to initialise anything with NULL. It's far better to initialise it with a reference to a real object.

Comment: @SteveC There are multiple cases when you can't initialise your pointer with a valid object right away. For example, you want to find a specific CFoo object in an array. 
`CFoo* pFooFound = NULL;`
`//Iterate through array...`
`pFooFound = array.getAt(i); //you found your object`
At the end of the loop, if you didn't find your object, your pointer will still be null and you can evaluate it `if(pFooFound == NULL)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local variables must be initialized before the compiler will allow you to use them (therefore, as Marko Topolnik commented, it is impossible to dereference an unitialized reference). Member variables (instance fields or static fields), on the other hand, are automatically initialized to `null` (references), 0 (primitive number types) or `false` (`boolean`) if you don't explicitly initialize them.

Comment: I would suggest renaming Fields to instance/class variables.

Comment: @JamesB Why? The same behavior applies to `static` variables.

Comment: Fields is not a term I'm used to hearing in the Java world.

Comment: @JamesB Get used to it. [It's the technical term for it.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)

Comment: @JamesB: I reworded it a bit, but I'm quite sure that _field_ is the "official" Java term for what many other languages call _member variable_.

Comment: @JamesB I think field is a valid term to use in Java, I've heard it enough to justify the use

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset +1 from me regardless!

Comment: Is there a java webpage documenting that?

Comment: @Goldorak84 Yes, the Java Language Specification that I've linked previously.

Comment: I found this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html - it actually used both terms lol

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was looking for a link stating what the default values were. here it is : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: This is annoying... why do local variables not automatically initialize to `null`, `0`, or `false`, the same way that instance and static fields do? It just seems like a pointless inconsistency in the language.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: That can probably only be answered by the language designers. My guess would be that they felt that local variables are more likely to have a desired initial value different from null/0/false, and that they wanted to prevent mistakes resulting from forgetting the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

In Java,
There are several kinds of variables:

Member variables in a class—these are called fields.

Variables in a method or block of code—these are called local variables.

Variables in method declarations—these are called parameters.

Member Variables will automatically initialized with their default values(0 for primitive number types, false for boolean and null for reference types) if you do not initialize them explicitly.